# Isn't it possible to use multiple try except statement?

Tags: python, try-except

I aim to catch errors so that wrong keywords from the users won't cause a breakdown of the code. Since there are different inputs for specific purposes, I couldn't use just one try/except block. To print the correct data linked to each input, I put the input in the except block, so that when the user types the wrong key, the computer will repeat the same question till the right input is passed in.
The error I'm encountering now is: only the first input in the first except block keeps getting printed to the terminal. What can be the possible problem? Thanks as you review the code below.

```
 data =  data_record = {
        "Age groups": {"teens": teens, "youths": youth, "adult": adult, "oldees": oldees},
        "Gender": {"males": males, "females": females},
        "classified bmi": {"underweight": underweight, "healthy": healthy, "overweight": overweight,
                           "obese": obese}}
    
    population = {"P of oldees per region": {
                                               "p of northeast oldees": p_northeast_oldees,
                                               "p of southeast oldees": p_southeast_oldees,
                                               "p of northwest oldees": p_northwest_oldees,
                                               "p of southwest oldees": p_southwest_oldees,
                                               # "percent ratio of oldees per region": percent_ratio_of_oldees_per_region
                                           }}
    
    data_keys = []
    data_values = []
    population_keys = []
    population_values = []
    for key in data_record.keys():
        data_keys.append(key)
    for key in population_record.keys():
        population_keys.append(key)
    for value in data_record.values():
        data_values.append(value)
    for value in population_record.values():
        population_values.append(value)
    
    data_key_and_values = {key: value for key, value in zip(data_keys, data_values)}
    population_key_and_values = {key: value for key, value in zip(population_keys, population_values)}
    
    print(f'''
    Welcome to Medical Insurance Analysis.
    As an intro, there are two types of information you can further analyze or examine: the data and the population 
    of each data. 
    Please note that any point you see P or p, it stands for population
        ''')
    
    
    def navigation(report=report):
        count = 0
        while count == 0:
            try:
                keys_request = input(
                    'Please type "data" or "population" for you to see the information contained in either '
                    'of the two. ')
                if keys_request.upper() == "DATA":
                    print(f'''
            {", ".join(data_keys)} 
                    ''')
                elif keys_request.lower() == "population":
                    print(f'''
            {", ".join(population_keys)} 
                            ''')
            except ValueError:
                keys_request
            
            try:
                value_request = input(f'''
        Above are the keys to each data.
        Please type the exact case and spelling of any of the keys listed above to get further information: ''')
                for data in data_keys:
                    if value_request == data:
                        print(f'''
        {data_key_and_values[value_request]}
                ''')
                for data in population_keys:
                    if value_request == data:
                        print(f'''
        {population_key_and_values[value_request]}
                ''')
            except ValueError:
                value_request
            
            try:
                analyze = input(f'''
        Do you wish to add some report?, if yes, type the report:
        if no, please type no: ''')
                if analyze.lower() != "no":
                    report += analyze
                    print(report)
                else:
                    print("Good luck as you examine the data")
            except ValueError:
                analyze
            
            try:    
                permission = input("Do you wish to view another dataset? Enter yes or no ")
                while permission.lower() == "yes":
                    navigation()
                count += 1
                if permission.lower() == "no":
                    return '''
        Thanks for reviewing our dataset! Hope to see you around again'''
        
                    break
    
            except ValueError:
                permission
```

Comment: There's no need for `else: pass`. You don't have to have an `else:` statement for every `if`.

Comment: There's no point in having `break` after `return`, since `return` ends the function, which also breaks out of the loop.

Comment: Also, the `break` statement isn't inside a loop. Is there another loop around the code you posted?

Comment: `keys_request` by itself on a line doesn't do anything. Why do you have that in the `except` block?

Comment: Is this code that you're copying and pasting into the Python command prompt as a single statement? Because that's really not a maintainable way to work with code in the long run. (Already at this length it's hard for me to imagine putting up with.) You should learn how to use files and modules instead. If this is in a `.py` file, then you should understand that simply writing e.g. `keys_request` on a line by itself doesn't actually *do* anything; you need to either `return` to get information back from a function, or `print` to display it.

Comment: Yes, there is a loop around the code

Comment: You should print a message in the `except` blocks so you know which ones are being executed. It's not clear to me what could be causing ValueError exceptions in this code.

Comment: "but whenever I do so using multiple try-except statements for inputs, the first input (keys_request) keeps getting printed" I can't understand your description of the problem. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to: 1. create a shorter version of the code that causes the problem, and that others can run without modification. 2. explain how to run the program, including what input, in order to cause the problem. 3. explain exactly what happens, and what *should* happen instead.

Comment: Each of your `try/except` blocks works independently. I can't think of any way that having multiple of them could cause the first one to repeat.

Comment: Following the advice in those links, you should also try to trace through the logic of the code yourself first, carefully, in order to figure out what is actually happening. Do variables have the values you expect them to have, at each point? Which `except` block(s) is/are entered? Does that match your expectation?

Comment: keys_request is an input, i put it in the except block so that it can keep asking the same question whenever the user is typing the wrong key

Comment: Alright @KarlKnechtel, I will try to simplify the code.

Comment: @Barmar that's my question exactly, I have multiple try/except blocks that works independently, I don't understand why I am having such errors

Comment: @FaroukAyotunde If you want to keep asking the question you have to put `keys_request = input('...')` in the `except:` block.

Comment: There's nothing in any of this code that makes the loop restart before going to the next `try/except` block. If you had `continue` somewhere, it could restart.

Comment: I just edited the code as @KarlKnechtel advised

Comment: You can easily cut 8 lines off of this just creating your lists like this: `data_keys = list(data_record.keys())`